# Getting RAM info - Powershell

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, get-wmiobject

I have a list of PC's that i need to get the Physical Memory and the amount of memory slots available.  I have a list of PC's in a text file and i am using the "get-content" cmdlet.  This is what I have:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName (Get-Content "C:\TextFile.txt") | ForEach-Object {[math]::truncate($_.capacity / 1GB)}
```

When I run this, only the Memory total is displayed. My 2 questions are:

1) How can get the PC name to show up next to the corresponding number?

and

2) How can i add the total memory slots available to this as well?

Thank You!

Comment: You'd better use `CIM` cmdlets instead of `WMI`.

Answer (score 1):

DeviceLocator tells you the slot.

## Example

```ps1
$memoryBySlot = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_PhysicalMemory | Foreach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject] @{
        CapacityGB = $_.Capacity /1GB
        DeviceLocator = $_.DeviceLocator
        ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    }
}
$memoryBySlot | Out-String

$memoryBySlot | Measure-Object -Property CapacityGB -Sum | select count, sum, property
```

## Results

```
CapacityGB DeviceLocator ComputerName
---------- ------------- ------------
        16 DIMM1         MYMACHINE
        16 DIMM2         MYMACHINE
        16 DIMM3         MYMACHINE
        16 DIMM4         MYMACHINE


Count Sum Property
----- --- --------
    4  64 CapacityGB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
Get-Content "C:\TextFile.txt" | % {$a = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $_ | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Capacity).Sum / (1024*1024*1024); [PSCUStOMOBJECT]@{"Computer"=$_;"MEM"=$a}} |export-csv 'file.csv'
```